# Summing over pair of indices (or more) in Python

Tags: python, numpy, sum

One way to calculate the Gini coefficient of a sample is using the relative mean difference (RMD) which is 2 times the Gini coefficient. RMD depends on the mean difference which is given by:

[image]

So I need to calculate each difference between pair of elements in a sample `(yi - yj)`. It took me quite a bit to figure out a way to do it but I want to know if there is a function that does this for you.

At first I tried this but I bet it's very slow in big data sets (by the way, s is the sample):

```
In [124]:

%%timeit
from itertools import permutations
k = 0
for i, j in list(permutations(s,2)):
    k += abs(i-j)
MD = k/float(len(s)**2)
G = MD / float(mean(s))
G = G/2
G
10000 loops, best of 3: 78 us per loop
```

Then I tried the following which is less understandable but quicker:

```
In [126]:
%%timeit
m = abs(s - s.reshape(len(s), 1))
MD = np.sum(m)/float((len(s)**2))
G = MD / float(mean(s))
G = G/2
G
10000 loops, best of 3: 46.8 us per loop
```

Is there something efficient but easy to generalize? For example, what if I want to sum over three indices?

This is the sample I was using:

```
sample = array([5487574374,     686306,    5092789,   17264231,   41733014,
         60870152,   82204091,  227787612,  264942911,  716909668,
        679759369, 1336605253,  788028471,  331434695,  146295398,
         88673463,  224589748,  128576176,  346121028])

gini(sample)
Out[155]:
0.2692307692307692
```

Thanks!

Comment: Is your question "I want an efficient way to calculate MD given the formula for MD"

Comment: Not really. MD is just an example to motivate my question. It's more like "I want an efficient and easy to understand way to sum over indices in general".

Comment: @RobertSmith Can you provide a sample so that I can compare the result of my code with yours?

Comment: Sure. Give me a few seconds.

Comment: I added a sample. See my update.

Comment: Is there a formulation that can use `(y_i - y_j)**2` for the kernel? If so you can use fast convolution in the frequency domain. Depending on the size of `s` and the particular FFT implementation this could be much faster, or no faster at all.

Comment: Do you have some reference about it? I'm not sure I understand what you mean.

Comment: FWIW I find that using `k=2*scipy.spatial.distance.pdist(s.reshape((len(s),1)),metric='cityblock').sum()` is several times faster than your second approach for longer arrays but slower for your `sample`.

Comment: Followup: of course, since it actually constructs an array, it'll hit memory problems. :-/

Comment: I'm not sure that approach is more understandable but it's definitely interesting. It also works for any number of indices.

Comment: @DSM the OP's `s - s.reshape(len(s), 1)` is also constructing an array.

Comment: @Jaime: yeah, but I can't see how to salvage it, whereas the first -- and admittedly slow -- OP solution could (if we lose the `list`) not use any extra space beyond `s` itself.

Answer (score 1):

For the MD example you give, it can be exploited by sorting, You can achieve O(N*Log(N)) instead of O(N^2)

```
y = [2,3,2,34]

def slow(y):
    tot = 0
    for i in range(len(y)):
        for j in range(len(y)):
            if i != j:
                tot += abs(y[i] - y[j])
    return float(tot)/len(y)**2

print slow(y)

def fast(y):
    sorted_y = sorted(y)
    tot = 0
    for i, yi in enumerate(sorted_y):
        smaller = i
        bigger = len(y) - i - 1
        tot += smaller * yi - bigger * yi
    return float(2*tot)/len(y)**2

print fast(y)
```

Often you will have to use dynamic programming or other techniques to make these faster, I'm not sure if there is a "one method fits all" solution.

Comment: Actually, your fast function is 208 times slower than In[126] (until the point of calculating MD). Most likely, a good solution needs to avoid any loops.

Comment: Hmm, how large is the sample? with my testing, large samples are a lot faster with my fast() method. In fact reshape() can't even run on samples larger than 10^4 it seems, whereas mine runs in less than a second on samples of size 10^6. For small samples your method may be faster due to the overhead of function calls etc.

Comment: Right. For small samples, the second code I showed is quicker but it becomes unbearably slower with larger samples, unlike yours that is fairly quick because you're using that trick of realizing that the original sum can be express as a sum of multiplications. Do you know how to extend this result to consider more indices?

Comment: ill have a think. probably by using inclusion exclusion or binary or ternary search.

Comment: So if it were yi + yj - yk, you could sort, then go through for each k, and have a rolling interval for the min yi and max yj that gives a sum greater than yk. that shows how much yk contributes. Similar for higher dimensions i suppose. Also you may be interested to read this answer which is very weakly related http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12946497/sub-on2-algorithm-for-counting-nested-intervals